# Django: how to store and display date times

Tags: database, django, timezone

With Django, can someone explain to me how DateTimes are stored in the Model/database and what is the best way to make sure that it is displayed correctly to the users? My users are all in the same timezone, but we have summer/winter time.

I'm thinking that DateTimes should be saved as GMP+1, but without summer/winter time. If a record has a DateTime that is 1 hour more than another one, then it should also have occurred 1 hour later. But how do I make sure that users see the correct time for this location? I'd prefer not to use the systime on their personal computers; all users should see the same date/times, regardless of where they are. They'll know that it is the time for this home location.

settings.py has TIME_ZONE, which I'm guessing is how the DB stores DateTime, but is this with or without summertime? And then I use other settings (template tags?) to convert the time? Which ones? Or is this also set in setting.py?

My app is hosted by webfactional, so I guess I'm not restricted by a Windows system, which apparently needs to use the system time.

Comment: Django has excellent docs on working with timezones. You should read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/

Comment: Always store the datetimes as UTC. Then use the timezone function(from pytz module) to display to the appropriate local time you want.